# Unable to read exception header from DLQ spring cloud stream kafka

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Using Spring cloud Stream Kafka listener to read message from kafka topic and incase of exception sending it to dead letter queue configuring the properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enable-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-name=book_error
```

I am able to send message to the DLQ . However when I try to read from DLQ so that I can take action based on Error Message . I am not able to read the exception embedded in the header.

```
@StreamListener("dlqChannel")
public void error(Message<?> message) {
    System.out.println("Handling ERROR: READING FROM DLQ");
    logger.info("header :" +message.getHeaders());
    logger.info("payload : " +message.getPayload());
    //return message;
}
```

The header payload seem to have object id which I cannot decipher. How do I parse the error and handle based on exception message.
Below is the header i get if I try to print it

```
header :{x-original-offset=[B@f82eb25, x-original-partition=[B@7a3b83c, deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedTopic=book_errors, kafka_offset=0, x-exception-message=[B@6dcc9872, x-exception-fqcn=[B@68079694, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@70449372, x-original-topic=[B@6a3ca71e, x-original-timestamp-type=[B@63baad23, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, x-original-timestamp=[B@37dd34f6, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1579990310188, kafka_groupId=bkerrgrp, x-exception-stacktrace=[B@6356ee7c}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception headers are `byte[]` - that's the only type Kafka supports. The various String-valued information is stored as `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`.

Use

```
String exceptionMessage = new String(message.getHeaders().get("x-exception-message", byte[].class), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Numeric values are stored using the appropriate types (int, long).

Use `ByteBuffer.wrap(header).getInt()` etc for those.

Here is the code that stores the headers...

```
kafkaHeaders.add(
        new RecordHeader(X_ORIGINAL_TOPIC, record.topic().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
kafkaHeaders.add(new RecordHeader(X_ORIGINAL_PARTITION,
        ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES).putInt(record.partition()).array()));
kafkaHeaders.add(new RecordHeader(X_ORIGINAL_OFFSET,
        ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES).putLong(record.offset()).array()));
kafkaHeaders.add(new RecordHeader(X_ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP,
        ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES).putLong(record.timestamp()).array()));
kafkaHeaders.add(new RecordHeader(X_ORIGINAL_TIMESTAMP_TYPE,
        record.timestampType().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
kafkaHeaders.add(new RecordHeader(X_EXCEPTION_FQCN,
        throwable.getClass().getName().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
kafkaHeaders.add(new RecordHeader(X_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE,
        throwable.getMessage().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
kafkaHeaders.add(new RecordHeader(X_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE,
        getStackTraceAsString(throwable).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

Comment: I'm always getting `org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException` for `X_EXCEPTION_FQCN`.
How can I sent root cause to DLQ in this header?

Comment: See the `Caused by` in the `X_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE` header.